# Cannot create a linked list from NULL

Tags: c, linked-list

In below code, I declared a binary linked list `Node *node = NULL` in function `main`, and intended to create a node in function `Test`. After that, `node` is still `NULL`. Why?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *left, *right;
} Node;

int Test(Node* node) {
    node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    node->value = 1;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    Node* node = NULL;
    Test(node);
    if(node) {
        putchar('0' + node->value);
    } else {
        putchar('n');
    }
    free(node);
    return 0;
}
```

Why this code prints `n` instead of `1`?

Comment: Remember that in C all function arguments are passed *by value*. Which means that the value of the arguments is *copied* into the argument-variable of the function. If the function modifies the argument-variable it's only this variable which is modified, the original variable used in the call will not be modified. Please do some research about *emulating pass by **reference** in C*.

Comment: Note that you could have also discovered something was wrong with your assumptions, had you used a dynamic analysis tool like Valgrind. It will tell you about a memory leak, hinting it's not working as you expected.

Comment: My recommendation would be to *return* the node instead of passing it. So you would have `Node* Test(void);` and in the `main` function do `Node* node = Test();`

Comment: I like how you are careful to not get uninitialized values; this is a solid experiment. `node` in `Test` and `node` in `main` just happen to have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy the Node ptr by reference, not by value. This is a great example of why pointers are considered difficult( and a reason why I use C++).
You successfully changed node in Test but the variables node in "main" and node in "Test" are different.

Test should look like

```
int Test(Node** node) {
    *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    (*node)->value = 1;
    (*node)->left = NULL;
    (*node)->right = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

and call Test with

```
Test(&node);
```

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to accept a double-pointer, but I would definitely pause to see if there is a better way. In this case, returning a pointer is probably a more natural design decision.

Answer (score 2):

This is because argument is passed by value. So, when you are passing node as argument to function, the actual NULL value is getting passed and any changes made to that value will not affect the node variable outside the function.